# Process Builder - Email Notifications

Tags: process-builder

I have an old process builder with scheduled actions that I have deactivated. The users are still receiving the email notifications. I have looked in Flows for what has been sent out, but I can't see the ones in the queue ready to go in order to delete them.

The criteria is based on an opportunity stage that doesn't exist no more.

What's best to do? Clone this PB, add the new opp stage in there and re-deactivate it? Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: you can delete scheduled actions using the [Flow Monitor](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_delete_instance.htm&type=5)

Comment: @cropredy - There are no pending ones, unfortunately. There are only the ones that have already been sent...

Answer (score 1):

> What Happens When the Associated Process Is Deactivated?

After you deactivate a process, the scheduled time for pending scheduled actions stays the same. If a deactivated process has pending scheduled actions and the record whose field the schedule is based on is changed, Salesforce recalculates the schedule for those actions.

After a process is deactivated, Salesforce ignores all other changes to the associated records.

Read more here:- [Transactions and Scheduled Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled_processing.htm&type=5)

Comment: Hi, thanks for coming back to me. I have found the same post myself, but what I am interested to know, if there is a way to stop the notifications going out as they confuse the users.